# Trailing zeros for rounded Pandas DataFrame after applying style

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to have all numbers rounded to two decimal places in my pandas table which I'm looking to visualise. When I do `df.round(2)` I get the desired output:

[image: Rounded to 2 decimal places as desired]

However, when I then apply a conditional styling to this table, I end up with trailing zeros.

```
df.round(2).style.apply(lambda x: ['background: cyan' if 1>x['target'] else 'background: yellow' for v in x], axis=1)
```

[image: Undesired: Leading zeros]

Any ideas how I can get rid of the trailing zeros while applying the conditional background style? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you set the `precision` from your actual format rather than rounding it before hand ? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html

Comment: Thanks both, the answers helped! Apologies, I should have carried out a better search on here.